# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in multi threading using boost threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, segmentation-fault

When try to run my program with up to 1 thread, it works fine for a while (some seconds or minutes) but finally get segmentation fault(core dumped) or double free(faststop ) error.

Here are the function which the threads run.

```
        //used in the Function
[Added]   typedef folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string*> PcapTask;
        struct s_EntryItem {
        Columns* p_packet; //has some arbitrary method and variables
        boost::mutex _mtx;
        };
        //_buffersConnection.wait_and_pop()
        Data wait_and_pop() {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
            while (the_queue.empty()) {
                the_condition_variable.wait(lock);
            }
            Data popped_value = the_queue.front();
            the_queue.pop();
            return popped_value;
        }
        struct HandlerTask {
            std::string year;
            folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string*> queue = NULL;
        };
        -----------------------------------------
        //The function which threads run
           void Connection() {
                std::string datetime, year;
                uint32_t srcIPNAT_num, srcIP_num;
                std::string srcIP_str, srcIPNAT_str, srcIPNAT_str_hex;
                int counter = 0;
                while (true) {
                    //get new task
                    HandlerTask* handlerTask = _buffersConnection.wait_and_pop();
                    PcapTask* pcapTask = handlerTask->queue;
                    year = handlerTask->year;                         
                    counter = 0;
                    do {
                        pcapTask->popFront();
                        s_EntryItem* entryItem = searchIPTable(srcIP_num);

                        entryItem->_mtx.lock();
                        if (entryItem->p_packet == NULL) {
                            Columns* newColumn = new Columns();
                            newColumn->initConnection(srcIPNAT_str, srcIP_str, datetime, srcIP_num);
                            entryItem->p_packet = newColumn;
                            addToSequanceList(newColumn);

                        } else {
                            bool added = entryItem->p_packet->addPublicAddress(srcIPNAT_str_hex, datetime);
                            if (added == false) {
                                removeFromSequanceList(entryItem->p_packet);
                                _bufferManager->addTask(entryItem->p_packet);

                                Columns* newColumn = new Columns();
                                newColumn->initConnection(srcIPNAT_str, srcIP_str, datetime, srcIP_num);
                                //add to ip table
                                entryItem->p_packet = newColumn;
                                addToSequanceList(newColumn);
                            }   
                        }
                        entryItem->_mtx.unlock();
                        ++_totalConnectionReceived;
                    } while (true);                        
                    delete pcapTask;
                    delete handlerTask;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ask your debugger, or valgrind.

Comment: @John Zwinck no idea about the code?

Comment: http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#locking-mutex

Comment: Yuck, `new`, `delete` and owning plain pointers everywhere. Why don't you use smart pointers?

Comment: @DanMašek Hmm, smart pointers!! I will think about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Valgrind, its very easy. Build your app in debug config and pass program executable to valgrind. It can tell you wide spectre of programming errors occuring in your app in runtime. The price of using Valgrind is that program runs considerably slower (some times tens times slower) than without Valgrind. Specically, for example, Valgrind will tell you where your your programs' memory was free'ed first when it tried to free it second time when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's the problem, but...

Are you sure that you must call `delete` over `pcapTask`?

I mean: you `delete` it but `queue` in `struct HandlerTask` is a class member, not a pointer to a class.

Suggestion: try to comment the line

```
delete pcapTask;
```

at the end of `Connection()`

**--- EDIT ---**

Looking at you added `typedef`, I confirm that (if I'm not wrong) there is something strange in your code.

`pcapTask` is defined as a `PcapTask` pointer, that is a `folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string*>` **pointer**; you initialize it with a `folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string*>` (**not** pointer)

I'm surprised that you can compile your code.

I think you should, first of all, resolve this antinomy.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I did not mention one line of code, unfortunately. It is added now to the question body. Nevertheless you think that is the problem ?

Comment: @m.r226 - I don't know but I'm surprised that you can compile your code: if I'm not wrong, `pcapTask` is defined as a `PcapTask` pointer, that is a `folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string*>` **pointer**; you initialize it with a `folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string*>` (**not** pointer)